# Ruby on Rails i18n activerecord custom messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-i18n

I have a ruby on rails application. I have spanish and english support in my application. However, I get a translation missing exception in case spanish mode.

I have the following model:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name,  length: { in: 5..15,  message: :bad_name }
end
```

en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        company:
          attributes:
            name:
              bad_name: 'message in english'
```

sp.yml

```
sp:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        company:
          attributes:
            name:
              bad_name: 'message in spanish'
```

Just in case the error when I open the application in english. I get the "message in english" message and that's ok.

On the other hand, when I open and test it in spanish, I get the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   translation missing: sp.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

I can't see what I'm missing,

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the snippet of code where you are setting a locale and creating a company ?

Answer (score 0):

Are other translations work in this file?
Try to rename sp.yml to es.yml, because this is the iso-code for "espanol".

Also try to include a message for activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid in your spansih file. will this be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to use Spanish within your locale you would need to set `I18n.locale = :es`. I think you mixed up your locales. The correct language file should be named `es.yml` and look like:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        company:
          attributes:
            name:
              bad_name: 'message in spanish'
```